# Cancel from Android Camera capture screen return to home page

Tags: android, android-camera

I got a problem to capture photo from camera. After I pressing the "Cancel" or "Confirm" button, it will return to Home page instead of the Activity which start the camera. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                            
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

What could be wrong in my code? Thanks

**Edit 1:**

This is my code for the button click listener:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener m_dialogOnclick = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        switch (which) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                            
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
                break;

            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

And the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code for click listeners for the buttons? And did you add the permission to use camera in the manifest file

Comment: By the way, there is no any error message.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the `onActivityResult` method?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Do something
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```